# Getting QGIS Print Composer flat?

Tags: qgis, qgis-print-layouts

I would like to get my print composer map flat for printing and output and look the same as my ArcGIS Pro layout. I have only been using QGIS for a week, trying to replicate my ArcGIS Pro work. Scale in ArcGIS Pro is 1:2,250 and rotation is 120.

Can anyone suggest settings to change?

See pictures of QGIS top and ArcGIS Pro bottom.

[image: QGIS Layout]

[image: ArcGIS Pro Layout]

I have found that the OSMM topo layers and imagery are in the image coordinate/projection system and most of my other layers are in coordinate system, when a project the features to the same as OSMM the layer ends up miles away, where as in arcgis pro it stays in the same place, I don't want to re-create these features its taken ages.

Any further suggestions

[image: OSMM Image]
[image: Rings Feature]

Comment: it looks like your project is set to a different projection than your data.  Make sure all your data is in the same projection and then set your project to use that projection.

Comment: Also if your issue is distortion of WMS raster data (your satellite imagery) when rotated in the Print Composer, you should load it using Tile Server/XYZ Tiles (see here for an example http://felix.rohrba.ch/en/2017/easily-add-tilemap-layers-qgis/) Using QuickMapServices and other plugins doesn't work.